# Rosbag Record Until Disk is Almost Full

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS1 Noetic on a high altitude balloon payload running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 collecting camera imagery and other sensor data.  During the first flight it worked well but filled up the sd card and prevented future booting of the Pi.  I could recover the data but never boot the Pi again.  For the second flight, a more elegant solution is to stop the recording of ROS bags right before the disk fills up.  The `rosbag record` command has an argument for `max_splits`, but it deletes existing files.  I am more interested in the data it collects in the air at the beginning of the flight than the data of it sitting on the ground waiting to be recovered.  Here is the record command I am using:

```
rosbag record -o ~/bagfiles/flight --split --size=4096
```

What is the most reliable way of stopping the rosbag recording just before the storage fills up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375343/rosbag-record-until-disk-is-almost-full/) by [matthew.castleberry](https://answers.ros.org/users/72871/matthew.castleberry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the easiest thing would be to predetermine a maximum size or duration then use the `--size=SIZE` or `--duration=DURATION`  flags without `--split`.  The recording node will stop at the size/duration you set.  The [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) mentions the `--duration` flag on its own, but for some reason only shows the `--size` flag in conjunction with `--split`.  Note that `DURATION` defaults to seconds, but you can set it in minutes or hours; and `SIZE` is in MB.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthew.castleberry](https://answers.ros.org/users/72871/matthew.castleberry/) on 2021-04-10**:
Maybe I was complicating it a bit, but based on your suggestion, I can calculate how much space is available on the flash card and use that as the `--size` argument in MB.  Since I have concern the battery has a chance of dying before it runs out of space due to numerous factors, I can just use `max_splits` as a multiplier of a smaller file size to ensure I do not fill up all the storage.